# MySQL grouping results by time periods

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp, group-by

I have a table that contains timestamps of session events. 
I want to query how many sessions I have according to the timestamps when 2 sessions are separated by at least 10 minutes difference of events. 
Can I count the sessions with an MySql query ?

Thanks

Comment: Could you show your table structure. Some data. And the queries you already tried, please?

Comment: first, yes this is possible but your question is way to vague to tell what would be a good approach. Second, given from your "10 minutes difference of events" I smell a requirment for an automatic logout after user inactivity? that can be solved without harrassing the database

Comment: it is not really an automatic logout, but if the user was idle for 10 minutes, it's indicate that there were two separate activities

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With little info on your tables this is no more than a basic idea for you, but you could do something like this:-

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT a.TimeStamp AS ThisTimeStamp, MIN(b.TimeStamp) AS NextTimeStamp
    FROM SomeTable a
    INNER JOIN SomeTable b
    ON a.TimeStamp < b.TimeStamp
    GROUP BY a.TimeStamp
) Sub1
WHERE Sub1.ThisTimeStamp < (Sub1.NextTimeStamp - 600)
```

Get all the timestamp and join them against all other timestamps that are greater, and use MIN to narrow that down to the next greatest timestamp. Then from that select the count where the difference is less than 600 seconds (assuming unix timestamps).

EDIT - If you want the tied down for the number of 10 minute+ gaps in events for users then:-

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT a.user_id, a.TimeStamp AS ThisTimeStamp, MIN(b.TimeStamp) AS NextTimeStamp
    FROM SomeTable a
    INNER JOIN SomeTable b
    ON a.TimeStamp < b.TimeStamp
    AND a.user_id = b.user_id
    GROUP BY a.user_id, a.TimeStamp
) Sub1
WHERE Sub1.ThisTimeStamp < (Sub1.NextTimeStamp - 600)
```

Comment: Thanks, 
The table has the event_id(bigint), event_date(datetime), user_id(bigint), event_content(varchar).
I need to count the number of event groups separated by at least 10 minutes.

Comment: What defines an event group? Just the user_id? If so I have added an edit

Comment: yes, it's only the userid. however, I am trying to run this query and it's not returning...

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with it obvious. Could you post the table declares and a bit of sample data?