# SQLrange queries with the highest priority

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Need help on the below query, considering the following on my table which is called 'tbProduct'.

```
CCY COUNTRY_CODE    FX_RATE
EUR      SG          0.80
USD      UK          0.50
USD      US          1.00
USD      SG          0.60
GBP      UK          1.00
GBP      SG          1.40
```

Above table in SQL;

```
CREATE TABLE tbProduct
    ([CCY] varchar(8), [COUNTRY_CODE] varchar(8), [FX_RATE] varchar(8))
;

INSERT INTO tbProduct
    ([CCY], [COUNTRY_CODE], [FX_RATE])
VALUES
    ('EUR', 'SG', '0.80'),
    ('USD', 'UK', '0.50'),
    ('USD', 'US', '1.00'),
    ('USD', 'SG', '0.60'),
    ('GBP', 'UK', '1.00'),
    ('GBP', 'SG', '1.40')
;
```

I need to get one fx rate for each of the currency from the table above based on the priority assigned to country code; the idea i am getting at is to pick the fx rate corresponding to the country with the highest priority for each currency. The priority in this case for example;

```
US > 1, UK > 2, SG > 3
```

so ideally i am looking for the SQL query to presented the below expected outcome.

```
CCY COUNTRY_CODE    FX_RATE
EUR     SG           0.80
USD     US           1.00
GBP     UK           1.00
```

This is my [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2fdbc/1).

Could someone show me how to get the expected outcome? Becuase im a confused on how to attempt this.

Thanks

Comment: What do the priorities mean?  I don't get it.

Comment: if there is a FX_RATE with Country_Code US, UK and SG
he wants to have the FX_RATE of the row with Country_Code = US as result

Comment: maybe i didn't explain myself correctly, so US > 1, UK > 2, SG > 3 is basically a key indicator. i need to write a SQL query that will return the value that matches close to that key indicator for each currency. I have shown the expected outcome what it needs to be. I hope this helps

Comment: If this is going to be a [series of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44625398/), consider accepting answers before moving on.

Comment: @Esteban P. are you able to show me in my fiddle how to acheive the outcome?

Comment: @dave . . . With the priorities you specify, US would be chosen for all currencies.  The expression `US > 1, UK > 2, SG > 3`, does not represent priorities.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` with a `CASE` expression in the `ORDER BY` clause in order to prioritize:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT CCY, COUNTRY_CODE, FX_RATE,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CCY 
                             ORDER BY CASE COUNTRY_CODE
                                         WHEN 'US' THEN 1
                                         WHEN 'UK' THEN 2
                                         WHEN 'SG' THEN 3
                                      END) AS rn
   FROM tbProduct
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
```

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/JOIY50192)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a Priority table and use `ROW_NUMBER` and `TOP 1 WITH TIES`

```
Declare @Priority as Table
(
    [COUNTRY_CODE] varchar(10),
    Priority int    
)

Insert Into @Priority VALUES ('US', 1), ('UK', 2),('SG', 3)


select TOP (1) WITH TIES 
       tp.* 
from tbProduct tp
Inner join @Priority p on tp.[COUNTRY_CODE] = p.[COUNTRY_CODE]
Order by row_number() over(partition by tp.CCY ORDER BY p.Priority)
```

Demo link: http://rextester.com/JDN95847