# MySQL counting the number of rows where the time is x seconds apart

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a database table (raw_data) where there are multiple rows. I am looking to count the number of rows between a given time interval (9:25:00 and 9:29:59) by grouping the rows if the time difference between each row is less than or equal to 2 seconds.

For example:

```
EventId Date    Time
1   2019/10/16  9:27:08
2   2019/10/16  9:27:11
3   2019/10/16  9:27:37
4   2019/10/16  9:27:40
5   2019/10/16  9:27:45
6   2019/10/16  9:27:45
7   2019/10/16  9:27:45
8   2019/10/16  9:27:57
```

the data in this snippet should yield a count of 6 (when counting items that are less than 2 seconds from each other). I.e. if an item is less than 2 seconds from the next row, chances are its the same event and therefore grouped together.

Much appreciated

Have attempted queries like:
(found at: [MySQL grouping results by time periods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17339650/mysql-grouping-results-by-time-periods))

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT a.starttime AS ThisTimeStamp, MIN(b.starttime) AS NextTimeStamp
    FROM raw_data a
    INNER JOIN raw_data b
    ON a.starttime < b.starttime
        and a.startdate = b.startdate
        where a.startdate ='2019-10-16' 
        and a.starttime >= '09:27:00' and a.starttime < '09:28:00' 
        and b.startdate ='2019-10-16' 
        and b.starttime >= '09:27:00' and b.starttime < '09:28:00' 
    GROUP BY a.starttime
) Sub1
WHERE Sub1.ThisTimeStamp < (Sub1.NextTimeStamp - 2)
```

purposefully hard coding the dates and times and comparing the results manually but the result always end up being different from the manual count.

Comment: "Gaps and Islands" is a term I recently learned to describe this sort of thing. You're basically looking to define all of the islands, and then count the islands. See https://bertwagner.com/2019/03/12/gaps-and-islands/ for a better example that should give you a start. That example isn't an exact answer for what you're trying to do (it matches date overlap vs. you're doing events within 2 seconds of each other), but I think it's still the general problem you're looking to solve.

Comment: yes but the problem becomes alot harder when he is using a MySQL version which does not support window functions.. @WOUNDEDStevenJones .. Also that link seams be be related to SQL Server (MSSQL) SQL dialect and not MySQL SQL dialect..

Comment: @Elad I think you also will need to better define "less than 2 seconds from the next row". What about data with timestamps like `:41, :41, :42, :43, :44, :45, :46` - how would you group those? (41, 41, 42), (43, 44), (45, 46)? Or is it all a single group because each one is less than 2 seconds from the next one?

Comment: @RaymondNijland correct - it's not a direct answer to their problem, but I'm showing an example as well as providing a potential search term for what they're trying to do.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones i never said it was totally wwrong but you should be aware posting links to other RDMS as resources.. As it is not always (directly) usefull SQL Server uses a different syntax then MySQL.. That `#` usage in SQL Server is a temporary table in MySQL you would have to use `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ..`

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry Edited the question with SQL attempts tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this table.

```
CREATE TABLE table2
    (`EventId` int, `Date` date, `Time` time)
;

INSERT INTO table2
    (`EventId`, `Date`, `Time`)
VALUES
    (1, '2019-10-16', '9:27:08'),
    (2, '2019-10-16, '9:27:11'),
    (3, '2019-10-16, '9:27:37'),
    (4, '2019-10-16, '9:27:40'),
    (5, '2019-10-16, '9:27:45'),
    (6, '2019-10-16, '9:27:45'),
    (7, '2019-10-16', '9:27:45'),
    (8, '2019-10-16', '9:27:57')
;
```

And this select statement

```
SELECT
  EventId,`Date`, `Time`
FROM
  (Select 
    EventId,`Date`, `Time`
    ,if (TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,@date_time,STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(`Date`, ' ', `Time`), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') ) > 2
    ,1,-1) inintrvall
    ,@date_time := STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(`Date`, ' ', `Time`), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') 
  From table2,
    (SELECT @date_time:= (SELECT min(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(`Date`, ' ', SUBTIME( `Time`, "5")), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') ) 
    FROM table2)) ti
  order by `Date` ASC, `Time` ASC) t1
WHERE inintrvall = 1
 order by `Date` ASC, `Time` ASC;
```

You will get 6 rows

```
EventId     Date        Time
1           2019-10-16  09:27:08
2           2019-10-16  09:27:11
3           2019-10-16  09:27:37
4           2019-10-16  09:27:40
5           2019-10-16  09:27:45
8           2019-10-16  09:27:57
```

Group by will not work on time intervalls.

so this little algorithm.
I check every row, if the prior row has a datetime older than 2 seconds
Then it marks it with 1 and if not with -1.

The ugly part is to get the actual datetime to better calculate the time differenz, for example when when a new day begins.

For these purposes it would be better to save the directy as timestamp or datetime.

Comment: Thank you nbk. What would the statement look like if I was able to change the date and time column to a datetime?

Comment: This **STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(`Date`, ' ', `Time`), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') **  produces a valid datetime, so if you have a column with datetime this code would disappear and replaced by your datetime.column

Comment: Amazing answer, not in a hundred years would I have solved this, thank you!!